# CKR_SESSION_READ_ONLY while creating a keystore by using keytool

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper, keystore, keytool

I am trying to create keystore using these commands:

```
openssl genrsa -out ./files/certificates/ca/rootCA.key 2048

openssl \
    req -x509 \
    -new \
    -nodes \
    -key ./files/certificates/ca/rootCA.key \
    -sha256 \
    -days 1024 \
    -out ./files/certificates/ca/rootCA.crt \
    -subj "/C=**/ST=***/L=****/O=***/OU=DevOps"
```

Then,  trying to create a truststore:

```
keytool -keystore zookeeper.truststore.jks -alias CARoot -import -file ./rootCA.crt -noprompt -storepass password
```

But it responds with the following error:

```
keytool error: java.security.KeyStoreException: sun.security.pkcs11.wrapper.PKCS11Exception: CKR_SESSION_READ_ONLY"
```

When running as `sudo`, the file is created empty, with `EOFException` exception.

It's hard to see anything meaningful on SO / documentation. Do you know why it happens? I've run it just fine on my Ubuntu WSL2 on Windows with Java 8:

```
openjdk version "1.8.0_275"

OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_275-8u275-b01-0ubuntu1~20.04-b01)

OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.275-b01, mixed mode)
```

Same command `keytool ...` on machine with RHEL 8.3 and Java 8 fails with the error above.

Answer (score 1):

Adding `storetype=jks` helped in running the command